# Insert or update based on primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't have a control over the sql query.

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name, age) VALUES(1, "A", 19)
```

Change should be done in the mysql server side. Is there a setting that can be enabled to achieve this. ? ( with out having to modify the insert query) 
id is the primary key.

```
 INSERT INTO table (id, name, age) VALUES(1, "B", 20)
```

Above query should ubdate the 1,A,19 row to 1,B,20.

Comment: There is no setting available to perform UPSERT. You have to modify the query.

Comment: @viki888 - where did you get that there isn't such a "setting"? It's called `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Please don't provide false knowledge if you're not sure about it yourself.

Comment: @Mjh In his question he said that he does not have control over sql query and he wanted it to be achieved through some setting in table schema.

Comment: There's no such setting in any kind of database. The guy's clearly new to all this, there's no need to go as far and categorically CLAIM that MySQL can't do it - of course it can. Just not like OP imagined it. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by slightly changing the syntax of the query. Some DB supports this.
I found this on internet need to verify with MySql.

```
INSERT INTO table
(id, name, age)
VALUES( 1, "A", 19)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
name = "B", age = 20;
```

In Postgres it is called upsert.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.  This does require changing the query.  I would suggest writing this as:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name, age)
    VALUES(1, 'B', 20) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name), age = VALUES(age);
```

This assumes that `id` is declared to be a primary key or at least `unique`.

The `VALUES` function is a handy way to pull the new values from rows being inserted.

Comment: That means it can't be done on mysql server side right?

Comment: @AsiriLiyanaArachchi . . . In other databases, you could use a trigger.  I don't think this would work in MySQL, because it doesn't support "instead of" triggers.